# Convert HTML umlauts to corresponding characters

Tags: html, characters

I have a list of strings containing german umlauts as their html representation, e.g. `ü` is `&uuml;` and so on. Is there an easy, maybe built-in, way to convert them within strings, i.e. `"Pr&uuml;fung"` should become `"Prüfung`"?

I found that [xml.el](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3138/built-in-way-of-decoding-html-entities-i-e-quot-or-39) does something similar but it depends on the entity code and does it the other way around, as far as I understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple function to do it. It has the list of German umlauts, the acute-accented E, and the SZ ligature. It can be pretty easily extended. There might be a better function somewhere in xml.el, but I can't find it now.

```
(defun de-escape (string)
  ""
  (let ((replacements '(("&Auml;" "Ä")
                        ("&auml;" "ä")
                        ("&Eacute;" "É")
                        ("&eacute;" "é")
                        ("&Ouml;" "Ö")
                        ("&ouml;" "ö")
                        ("&Uuml;" "Ü")
                        ("&uuml;" "ü")
                        ("&szlig;" "ß")))
        (case-fold-search nil))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert string)
      (dolist (replacement replacements)
        (cl-destructuring-bind (old new) replacement
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (while (search-forward old nil t)
            (replace-match new))))
      (buffer-string))))
```

Some example usages:

```
ELISP> (de-escape "Pr&uuml;fung")
"Prüfung"
ELISP> (de-escape "die B&auml;ren")
"die Bären"
ELISP> (de-escape "&Ouml;kologie")
"Ökologie"
```